# Did Ghast fireballs use to be to their own independent item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I remember in previous versions of Minecraft that the Fire Charge was not a craftable item, but rather the item ID of the Ghast's fireball. Is this true? I thought the ID of the Ghast's fireball might now be the same as the fire charge, but with a data value of 1 just like charcoal. Sadly, I don't think this is the case.

Mainly, I just want to launch Ghast fireballs out of dispensers.

Comment: Ghast fireballs are not items, and have never been items. They are entities. Essentially what happens when a ghast fires is they spawn a fireball entity with a specific velocity.

Comment: Why did someone -1 my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ghast fireballs are their own entity. Ghast fireballs are not, and never have been, an item; fire charges have been craftable since they were implemented and have never just been "the item ID of the Ghast's fireball".

Ghast fireballs used to use the texture of snowballs before the current fire charge texture, but were never actually either of those items.

There is no way to shoot them out of a dispenser, although you can `/summon` them.

Comment: The Ghast's fireballs' entity id is FireBall, and a blaze's and a firecharge shot out of a dispenser is SmallFireBall